# How to delete files from git bare remote repository?

Tags: git, git-remote

I have a remote bare git repository.

A new developer cloned it, but he didn't have a properly configured .gitignore file, so he mistakenly pushed some unwanted files into the remote. When I pulled the changes and merged, I got these previously untracked files. Others have also pulled the changes from the remote and have these unwanted files as well.

How do I delete these files from the remote repository, and everyone else's remote/origin/branches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a three step process:

1. Remove the files from your copy of the repository (either with [`git rm`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rm) or by [totally purging these files from your history](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) depending on how important it was that these files never be in the repository in the first place)
2. Push your changes back to the remote repository using [`git push --force`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).
3. Let everyone know that they can re-pull the repository - this will require a [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) of their work on the last know *good* commit.

As a last step you may also want to add the `.gitignore` file to the repository so that when the repository is cloned all the right files get ignored.

Answer (score 7):

See github have a FAQ on this: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data
Here are the steps:

1. Rewrite the tree from local (working) tree.

   $ git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Rakefile' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
2. Force push to remote.

   $ git push origin master --force
3. Everybody pull from the remote (and use `--force` if needed)

To prevent this from happening again, you should check the `.gitignore` in the repository (and optionally setup a hook on server)